# What inline code stops JAWS from saying 'onmouseover'?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, onmouseover, jaws-screen-reader

I'm in WordPress and I'm trying to make it accessible. This is very difficult because of the dozens of external CSS documents. I am thus forced to do inline styling.

JAWS is saying onmouseover in the following link:

```
<div  class="service_title">

<a href="/solutions/508-compliance/" onmouseover="this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'" onmouseout="this.style.textDecoration = 'none'" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; color: white; text-transform: uppercase;" title="View all Accessibility/Usability Solutions">Accessibility/Usability Solutions</a>
```

How can I keep the underline styling but stop JAWS from reading "onmouseover?"

Comment: JAWS is reading "onmouseover" because you added code that *could* be important to the JAWS user. If you are trying to make a site about accessibility, this is a bad way to show off your capabilities. You would be much better off styling your CSS through the :hover selector and removing this from code. If you are having trouble understanding how all the CSS documents fit together, you might want to spend some quality time deconstructing your site in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: Hi Tim, I understand where you're coming from however, I started working on someone else's WordPress website to make it accessible. I was asked to maintain all aspects of design including animations in making it accessible. This is why I asked this question and why I must include onmouseover. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why are you using events here instead of CSS? This is a textbook example of where to use :hover - and as a bonus, if you add a :focus rule, you can get underline on either mouse over or keyboard focus.